# sdkmanager not found after typing flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

**Getting error while typing flutter doctor --android-licenses**

> flutter doctor --android-licenses  **error:-** Android sdkmanager not found. Update
> to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are
> installed to resolve this.

**I have the updated version of Android SDK even i give the environment path**
**please any one give soln for that**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install [Command line tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orpn6.png), go to Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Android SDK Command-line-tools and its all.

After the installation do Flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

Solution to install cmdline tools in Android Studio Dolphin (linux):

- Open Android Studio
- On the home screen, on the top bar,to the extreme right of "Search Projects"click on the 3 dots
- Select SDK manager from the drop down menu
- Click on the SDK Tools tab
- Select and install Android SDK command tools